# GridView not visible in ContentPlaceHolder on content page

Tags: asp.net, gridview, master-pages, contentplaceholder

I am trying to create a page that uses a MasterPage to organize content.  On my content page, I have created a text search, which will filter a GridView presentation of data.

When I use the databinding in a non-master page setup, it works perfectly.  But, as soon as I drop the controls into a contentplaceholder on my page, it no longer displays any results.

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: show your code what you have tried ?

Comment: Have you registered the controls in the master page?

Comment: how do you register controls in the master page?  sorry this is the very first time i have tried using a master page setup.

Answer (score 0):

try these

- debug your page with breakpoints and be sure your gridview datasource is not null
- make sure you have registerd the controls in master page
- Sometimes it is due to css. also check css of content page
- try to make controls on content page not just copy and paste them from another page

To fatch the values from previous page store values in session and on second page

```
DataSet ds = (DataSet)(Session["id"]);
            Gridview1.DataSource = ds;
            Gridview1.DataBind();
```

Comment: Here is my textbox search page code, where clicking the button it postsback to my results page where the gridview is (search page is default.aspx and results page/with gridview is default2.aspx)

Comment: Here is my textbox search page code,(search page is default.aspx and results page/with gridview is default2.aspx)                          <%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="Default.aspx.cs" Inherits="_Default" %>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
<title></title>
</head>
<body>
<form id="form1" runat="server">
<div>
<asp:TextBox ID="CellLine" runat="server">%</asp:TextBox>
<asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" PostBackUrl="~/Default2.aspx" Text="Button" />
</div>
</form>
</body>
</html>

Comment: And thanks for the suggestions.  Just to emphasize:  i have one textbox, one search button which searches an database and returns a gridview on a separate aspx page.  If this is done on a plain page, (no master) it works perfectly.  If i think recreate the same code, but it is now placed (both the search textbox/button and the result gridview) in a aspx page that is linked to a masterpage (the controls and gridview sit in a contentplaceholder) the search returns no results, so no error, but no table shows up on the results page.

Comment: @user3124375 you are saying that you search on one page and want to show result on another page for this you have to store your dataset in session and then go to next page and on that page fatch values from session I updated the answer for second page